# Swift MapView not adding annotation to Map

Tags: swift, annotations, mkmapview

So for my mapView, I am receiving coordinates from another VC by passing it longitude and latitude through a global array like such:

Adding the latitude and longitude into the array:

```
var location_one: [String: Any] = ["title": eventName, "latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude]
    locations.append(location_one)
    if let tbc = self.tabBarReference {
        if let map = tbc.viewControllers?[1] as? MapVC {
            map.loadViewIfNeeded()
            map.add(newLocation:location_one)
        }
     }
```

Receiving the coordinates on the MapViewVC:

```
    func add(newLocation location_one:[String:Any]) {
        let momentaryLat = (location_one["latitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue
        let momentaryLong = (location_one["longitude"] as! NSString).doubleValue
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = location_one["title"] as? String
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: momentaryLat as CLLocationDegrees, longitude: momentaryLong as CLLocationDegrees)
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)

        //        self.map.centerCoordinate = annotation.coordinate
    }
```

viewForannotation code:

```
func mapView(_ map: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {



    let identifier = "pinAnnotation"
    var annotationView = map.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    }

    annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    return annotationView
}
```

The coordinates are properly transferring and the func add is being called upon (verified using a break statement), however when I go to the MapView in the simulator, the annotation isn't being placed. I have no idea what is going on, as this worked properly in another App I tested, but don't have a clue what could cause it to mess up.

I also have code that finds the user's current location and places a pin based on that... perhaps that could mess up the add coordinate code?

Comment: By any chance did you set the delegate to the map object and implemented the viewForAnnotation method?

Comment: @Rob the momentaryLat and momentaryLong receive the coordinates properly so I think that part is good. I have edited my question to include the viewForAnnotation. My app worked properly with displaying the current location's annotation so I'm not sure if I properly implemented it or not.

Comment: @apineda yep I set, self.map.delegate = self in my viewDidLoad(). Also, I've edited my question to include my viewForAnnotation method, however, I am not sure if I've implemented it properly.

Comment: So, I'd add a breakpoint in `viewFor` and examine the `annotation`. That kills two birds with one stone, (a) making sure you're reaching this bit of code correctly; and (b) that the annotation contains what you think it should.

Comment: @Rob I inserted a breakpoint in the viewFor. May I ask when this method is called? It didn't break until I switched the VC to the mapView in the simulator. I do not know much about viewForAnnotation method so I'm not sure if it is properly called on after I transfer the coordinates.

Comment: @Kevin that method is called just when the annotation is about to be displayed over the map. It returns the annotation object the map will later use.

Comment: @apineda - "It returns the annotation object the map will later use" ... not to split hairs, but it returns the annotation _view_ object, not the annotation object, which is different. I know you know that, but for folks not familiar with the distinction, it can be a source of confusion.

Comment: @Rob yeah, your clarification is totally correct and acceptable.

Comment: @Rob Ah I see. Could it be that the coordinate is not being placed because it is not on the visible portion of the map? My code has centered the view of the map on the user's current location and the coordinate I have been using is New York, which I need to zoom out to see whether an annotation was placed or not. Am I interpreting that correctly? Is the visible portion of the map the whole map or only the screen that is loaded on the simulator?

Comment: @Rob Great explanation, I understand now thanks. Also I revisited what you mentioned about the momentaryLat and momentaryLong being 0.0. I previously thought you meant something else, but when I printed the values to the console they did print out 0.0! You mentioned this to be a parsing issue.. could you explain further what may be up?

Comment: @Rob Hmm, I am not familiar with what raw JSON is and I don't think I am using JSON in my code. To help clarify my situation, I have the user input an address and I use a reverse geocoder to change the address into coordinates in my first VC. This process works, and then I transfer these coordinates into the MapView VC through the array. I did a similar idea in another project where I had the user input the coordinates into the first VC and then I transferred them to the MapView. This worked fine.. so perhaps it could be an issue with the reverse geocoder?

Comment: Sorry for introducing the JSON confusion. Just look at what `location_one["latitude"]` and `location_one["longitude"]` are before you convert them to doubles. Maybe there's some extraneous stuff in those strings. Maybe they're empty strings because this array wasn't populated correctly. Break the assignment of `momentaryLat` and `momentaryLong` into smaller steps and look at the values at each step of the process and the problem will likely jump out at you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest double checking the numeric values of `momentaryLat` and `momentaryLong`, because it's possible that due to parsing problems, they're not what you think they are (e.g. make sure they're not 0.0, in the Atlantic Ocean!). We'd have to see what `location_one["latitude"]` values were before you converted it to `NSString` and extracted the double value from that. Break it down into separate steps, and the problem will likely jump out at you.

---

Your `viewFor` looks fine. Unrelated, I'd suggest putting the `annotationView?.annotation = annotation` inside the `else` clause of the preceding `if` statement (no need to set the `annotation` if you just created the `MKPinAnnotationView` using that same `annotation` ... you only need to do this if reusing the annotation view). And I'd also generally check to make sure the annotation is not the `MKUserLocation` because we generally let the map view render that for us.

```
func mapView(_ map: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }   // let the OS show user locations itself

    let identifier = "pinAnnotation"
    var annotationView = map.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

But neither of those two observations have anything to do with your issue of the missing annotation.

---

Remember, the `viewForAnnotation` (or [`viewFor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview) in Swift 3) method is only called when one or more of the map's `annotations` has a `coordinate` that falls within the visible portion of the map and it therefore concludes that it needs to render the associated annotation views. So, one would not expect it to be called until (a) the map tries to draw itself and (b) one or more of the annotations have coordinates within (or near) the visible portion of the map.

For example, if you have 100 annotations added to the map object, of which only 10 fall within the visible portion of the map, only 10 annotation views will be created. And if you scroll the map such that 5 fall out of view and 7 more scroll into view, it call viewForAnnotation 7 more times, once for each newly visible annotation. The viewForAnnotation will likely successfully dequeue/reuse the 5 annotation views that scrolled out of view and and will only create new annotation views for the two additional ones. (It's more complicated than that, but that's the basic idea.)

It's analogous to table/collection views, where cells are created only for the visible cells. So, if you have 100 objects in your model, but only 12 rows are visible in a table, you'll create 12 cells only. And as a row scrolls out of view, it becomes available for dequeue/reuse for future rows that scroll into view. It's a common pattern that you'll see throughout iOS, where computationally-expensive view objects are only created as needed, and reused wherever possible.

Comment: breaking it down has helped a little! I realized that my code for putting the coordinates in my array wasn't in the right spot. Now after running it, the output for location_one["latitude"] is Optional("40.713054"), and momentary latitude is outputting 40.713054; however it is still not placing an annotation at the location.

Comment: OK, so you have the debugging skills to figure this out. Look at the `coordinate` value of the annotation object right before you add it to the map's array of `annotations`. Look at it in `viewFor`. Is the annotation just not in the right spot or is it not getting added at all for some reason?

Comment: I understand what the viewFor method does, but I'm having trouble understanding each line of code inside. I'm not quite sure what you mean to look for the coordinate value of the annotation in viewFor. The annotation before added to the array is: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007). And the annotation is not being placed at all.

Comment: I was just suggesting that you add a breakpoint in `viewFor` and print the `annotation` (or, the `coordinate` property of that `annotation`). It doesn't make sense that `viewFor` is getting called for your annotations (not just the `MKUserLocation`), but you're not seeing the pin on the map. The only thing that would account for that would be if you have multiple map view objects floating about (e.g. the one that you added in IB and another you instantiated programmatically). But first, let's make sure you're seeing `viewFor` called for the annotation you added to the map.

Comment: Ah ok. When I tried printing the annotation in the viewFor, nothing shows up, while in my function add, which receives the array coordinates, is able to print out the annotation. My other app that works in placing the annotation prints the annotation in the viewFor. So the issue is that the annotation is not passing through the viewFor. What could be the cause of this?